# Backbone collection view rendering

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

**I have problem with render my collection ... all working me when I add into console this :**

```
$('body').append(tablesView.render().el);
```

**I see all my names in li from json file. After that I can with :**

```
tablesCollection.create({ name:'Next Table Name' });
```

**add next object which is immediately rendered.**

**My code :**

```
 window.App = {

    Models: {},
    Views: {},
    Collections: {}
};

window.template = function (id) {

    return _.template($('id' + id).html());
};
```

//============================     TABLE MODEL

```
App.Models.Table = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
            name: 'Table Name',
        },
});
```

//======================     TABLES COLLECTION

```
App.Collections.Tables = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: App.Models.Table,

    url: 'tables.json'
});
```

//==============     VIEW EACH TABLE MODEL FROM COLLECTION

```
App.Views.Tables = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'ul',


    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.fetch({reset:true});
        this.collection.on('reset', this.render);
        this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this );

    },

    render: function () {

        this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);

        return this;

        },

    addOne: function(table) {

        var table = new App.Views.Table({ model: table });

        this.$el.append( table.render().el );

        table.render();

        }

});
```

//=============================     VIEW FOR ONE TABLE MODEL

```
App.Views.Table = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'li',

    initialize: function() {

      this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this)  

    },

    render: function () {

        this.$el.html( this.model.get('name') );

        return this;

    },
});
```

//================     NEW COLLECTION INSTANCE

```
var tablesCollection = new App.Collections.Tables();
```

//========================     NEW TABLES VIEW INSTANCE

```
var tablesView = new App.Views.Tables({ collection: tablesCollection });
```

Very thanks for every answer !!!!
Regards
Makromat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var fetch = mycollection.fetch();
fetch.done(function(){
   $(body).html(_.template(mytemplate, {obj: obj});
});
```

inside initialize collection view add this:

```
App.Views.Tables = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#content',

    template: _.template('<h1>My template</h2>'),

    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new App.Collections.Tables();
        this.collection.fetch({reset:true});
        this.collection.on('reset', this.render);
        this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this );

    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template());
    }
```

....

Comment: Thanks for answer !! Now I have again edited code ... please check

Comment: (updated my answer), try to add reset to initialize in tables view. Updated jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hfYHm/3/

Comment: looks like this.collection is not instantiated within the view. updated my answer.

Comment: still nothing.... I have added console.log('initialized'); in initialize function with your code and not working...

Comment: now I have added tablesView = new App.Views.Tables(); and in console is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'empty' of undefined

Comment: now you can see my code jsfiddle.net/makromat/A3F6G/3/ when I add to console $('body').append(tablesView.render().el); all is working... I see tables in browser and I can add next table with tablesCollection.create({ name:'Tablexxx' });

Comment: but only when I add $('body').append(tablesView.render().el); in console ... I don't know where I need to add in code for same function

Comment: add 'el' to initialize and then you can append or .html to that element. I update my answer.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'template'

Comment: still not showed only after add $('body').append(tablesView.render().el);

Comment: alexndm please you don't know where I have problem ?

Comment: Can you add html to jsfiddle? Usually you need to include underscore library, and use its templates to render data on a page, instead of appending it.

Comment: Thanks very much jsfiddle.net/makromat/hfYHm/4/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37605/discussion-between-matej-marko-and-alexndm)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are waiting for the result of the asynchronous [fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) operation before trying to render the collection:

```
tablesCollection.fetch({
    success : function(collection, response, options){
     var tablesView = new App.Views.Tables({ collection: tablesCollection });
     $(document.body).append(tablesView.render().el);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but Where I can add your code ? I have this on jsfiddle.net/makromat/hfYHm/1